# JQuery/Javascript sources allowing "image template" text editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, image-editing

I'm looking for any code resources that make it possible to navigate between images that act as a "image template" picker, and then having fields off to the side where you can place text, which gets superimposed on the image-template, and allows the image/text to then be saved as a whole, downloadable jpg/png file.

I'm not looking for a service, but rather source code and possibly a demo along with it.

Comment: you have 3 options - svg, canvas or dom

Comment: @llamerr Do you possibly know of any existing projects out now that do this already? Things I could either buy or download with source code that allows this to be demo'ed and tested.

Comment: no, but i think you need to search for some `image editor` maybe. https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs (i haven't seen text editing options, but it states `Extensible`  so maybe there's some plugins for text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough.. I found the exact solution I was looking for. It was a meme generator.

http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-meme-maker/3516440?ref=jqueryrain